# AWS IAM: allow IAM user to change EC2 instance type only

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I'm trying to write a policy that would allow a group of users to change the instance type of any instance, but no other attributes.

I currently have:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1471613026000",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:ModifyInstanceAttribute"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

but this would allow them to change any of the instances' attributes. Is there a way to restrict this to allow changing the instanceType attribute only?

Comment: I think if you allowed your users run only certain type of instanses it will be solution.

Comment: I don't think so, as this would still allow them to change any attribute of instances with the chosen instanceType(s).

Answer (score 2):

You can limit what attribute can be edited with a conditional:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1471613026000",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:ModifyInstanceAttribute"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "ec2:Attribute": "InstanceType"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

EC2 policy docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-policy-structure.html#amazon-ec2-keys